# passing array value to url in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm passing the array value to url like this 
view code

```
from_multiselect('functio[]',$function,'','id=function')
```

**baseurl/test/roles?id=1,2,3**

this is my jquery

```
$("#role > option").remove(); 
var id = $('#function').val(); 
alert(id);
var str=new Array();

alert(id);
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "test/roles?id="+id, 
   success: function(roles) 
   { 
     alert(roles);
     $.each(roles,function(id,roles) 
     {
        var opt = $('<option />'); 
        opt.val(id);
        opt.text(roles);
        $('#role').append(opt); 
     });
   }
 });
 });
});
```

Page give error **when i pass the array value in url**  like  **Disallowed Key Characters.**

Thank in advance

Comment: Is your PHP framework "CodeIgniter"?

Comment: yes gill its codeigniter

Comment: Then plz try my answer, it might work~

Answer (score 0):

and then post this array like this:

```
$("#role > option").remove(); 
var id = $('#function').val(); 
var valArray = id.split(',');
var str=new Array();

alert(id);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test/roles?id="+valArray, 
success: function(roles) 
{ alert(roles);
$.each(roles,function(id,roles) 
{
var opt = $('<option />'); 
opt.val(id);
opt.text(roles);
$('#role').append(opt); 
});
}
});
});
});
```

in the method add parameter to accept array.

Answer (score 0):

This is CodeIgniter error.

So, to solve this, please go to

`/application/config/config.php`

AND

search for

`$config['permitted_uri_chars']`

change to:

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\+-,?&=';`

Comment: do one thing: replace 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\+-,?&='; by '';

Comment: it just take first values result like it passes 5,2,3,it give the 5 result